# (JCalc) What is proper naming of classes and method when designing API for calculation library

Tags: java, api

I'm working on library which will provide easier writing and calculation in Java using fluent API.
Library have implemented basic functionalities and now I working to improve API.

I follow (most of) instruction given by http://theamiableapi.com/2012/01/16/java-api-design-checklist/

But still I have some doubts in naming some classes, methods.
So I have several question oriented on naming those.

1. For calculation there is basic class Calculator, and for execute calculation, there is method 'calculate'.
   Which is more preferable name 'calculate' or simplified 'calc'
2. Calculator class have ability to track each step of calculation, 
   For now I have those methods:

   - setTrackSteps(boolean)  which enable tracking each step of calculation
   - getTrackedSteps()       return list of each step in TrackedStep object
   - hasTrackedStep          check is tracking calculation steps is enabled/disabled
     Does somebody have some better suggestions for those names?
3. Calculator.getTrackedSteps() return list of object TrackedStep.
   TrackedSteps is little harsh name.
   So I'm trying to find some better name?
4. I separate public API with internal implementations into internal package.
   In this package I have 'Utils' class with static methods and I'm trying to avoid this generic name.
   Maybe HelperUtils?
   I'm trying to avoid prefixes with Calc or Calculator, because when end user use some IDE and when it start writing Cal.. IDE will provide several classes which start with Cal.. including 'Calc..Utils'

If somebody is more interested into api it's available at [GitHub](https://github.com/d-sauer/JCalcAPI) and from [project webpage](http://www.jdice.org)

Answer (score 1):

Some people might consider this as "Primarily Opinion Based". And given that you have existing code, and want (sort of) opinions about this, some people might refer you to [CodeReview StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). However, there there are some common best practices when it comes to API design, so this might be OK. Nevertheless, the following points are slightly vague recommendations, and you should not base your decisions solely on one answer from a Q&A site.

---

**1.**: I agree with the point mentioned in the checklist:

> 2.2.11. Avoid abbreviations

So the name `calculate` should be preferred. People with an IDE will anyhow just type `.c...` and then hit CTRL+Space...

**2.**: According to the usual conventions used for boolean properties, the methods could alternatively be called `setTrackingSteps(boolean)` and `isTrackingSteps()`, respectively, which is in line with the checklist:

> 3.7.2. Start the name of methods returning Boolean properties with “is”, “can” or similar
>
> 3.7.3. Start the name of methods updating local properties with “set”

**3.**: I'm not sure what you mean by "harsh". Are there steps that are not Tracked? If not, the type could simply be called `Step` instead of `TrackedStep`.

**4.**: Does this `Utils` class really have to be `public`? When in doubt, leave it out. The name `HelperUtils` seems like a tautology. In any case, the actual name mainly depends on *what the methods in this class have in common*. From a short glance at the code, I see two methods:

```
public static boolean equals(Object objA, Object objB) {...}

public static Num[] toNums(Object... object) { ... }
```

Depending on whether this class *really* has to be public, and whether there are further methods to be added, an appropriate name until now could just be `Objects` (also see [Guava Objects::equals](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#equal%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)). This would allow a usage that would look like prose:

```
if (Objects.equal(objectA, objectB)) {
    Num nums[] = Objects.toNums(objectA, objectB);
    ... 
}
```

The latter method could also be contained in a class called `Nums`, to be called as `Nums.fromObjects(...)`.

---

BTW: When it comes to API design, I can absolutely recommend the talk about [How to design a good API - and why it matters](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/effective-api-design) by Joshua Bloch. Additionally, you might find the [API Design Wiki](http://wiki.apidesign.org/wiki/Main_Page) interesting: It is created by Jaroslav Tulach, the founder and initial architect of NetBeans.